# PSQL dense_rank of one item out of distinct total items

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, dense-rank

I'm able to use the following PSQL query (at the end) to get the `dense_rank` of a single row in my table, however, I would like to be able to display this as:

`dense_rank OUT OF total distinct ranks`

For example, since `dense_rank` allows for 'ties', so to speak, if I have 100 rows and the chosen row is ranked 14th (and there are only 59 distinct ranks), I would like to say:

`Ranked 14th out of 59`

Is there a way I can modify my query to achieve this or will I have to use multiple queries?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT ranked.*
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          postable_id,
          spread_count,
          bury_count,
          read_count,
          (spread_count*3) + (bury_count*-2) + (read_count*-1) AS score,
          dense_rank() OVER (
                             ORDER BY (spread_count*3) + (bury_count*-2) + (read_count*-1) DESC) AS RANK
   FROM posts) AS ranked
WHERE id = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT ranked.*, 
      RNK||' out of '||MAX(RNK) OVER() as rnk_pos
      FROM
       (SELECT id,
          postable_id,
          spread_count,
          bury_count,
          read_count,
          (spread_count*3) + (bury_count*-2) + (read_count*-1) AS score,
          dense_rank() OVER (
                             ORDER BY (spread_count*3) + (bury_count*-2) + (read_count*-1) DESC) AS RNK
        FROM posts) AS ranked
      ) t
WHERE id=?
```

Comment: This seems to work @vkp, thank you!  Can you explain this black magic if you have time?  Much appreciated.

Comment: @lightyrs .. the only additional thing i added is `MAX(RNK) OVER()` which gets the maximum rank (i.e 59 in this example). `RNK` is what you already calculated. concatenating them gets you what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*
             (spread_count*3) + (bury_count*-2) + (read_count*-1) AS score,
             dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY (spread_count*3) + (bury_count*-2) + (read_count*-1) DESC) AS RANK,
             count(distinct (spread_count*3) + (bury_count*-2) + (read_count*-1)) over () as outof
      FROM posts p
     ) p
WHERE id = ?;
```

Alas, that doesn't work because Postgres does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT)` as a window function.  You can implement it using other window functions:\

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by score desc) AS RANK,
             sum( (seqnum = 1)::int) as outof
      FROM (SELECT p.*,
                   (spread_count*3) + (bury_count*-2) + (read_count*-1) AS score,
                   row_number() over (partition by (spread_count*3) + (bury_count*-2) + (read_count*-1) AS score order by spread_scount) as seqnum
            FROM posts p
           ) p
     ) p
WHERE id = ?;
```